# Rename a single file whose ending is unknown

Tags: rename, mv

Imagine I have this file in a certain directory

```
chromedriver_97.0.4692.71
```

By default I don't know the ending after `_` (I download it from the web, and this is for a script), and I want to rename it to simply `chromedriver`

Though when I do

```
mv chromedriver* chromedriver
```

I get this error:

```
mv: target 'chromedriver' is not a directory
```

The `mv` command thinks I am trying to move it into a directory, but I am just trying to rename it. Can I use `mv` for this?

Comment: This looks like a job for Larry Wall's `rename` (there is more than one `rename` command floating around. This one may be of help. It does `sed` but for filenames. However, if you can't specify a one-to-one or many-to-many relationship, then it is probably impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mv: target 'chromedriver' is not a directory
> ```

> The mv command thinks I am trying to move it into a directory,

No, it's not! It **complains** you're **not** moving into  directory – exactly because there's multiple files that match your globbing pattern `chromedriver*`.

First of all, you said that unknown part of the file name always comes after `_`, so use `chromedriver_*` instead of `chromedriver*`. But if there's still multiple candidates, what you want is simply impossible - you're trying to rename multiple files to one name.

So, we couldn't fix that for you – you'll have to figure out a way to pinpoint the one file you want to rename.

Also, this sounds very much like a job for a *symbolic link*, not for renaming!

Comment: you were indeed right

Comment: FWIW, to rename the first (in lexical order) file whose name starts with `chromdriver_` to `chromedriver`, in zsh, you'd do `mv chromedriver_*([1]) chromedriver`